# Help with some references

Tags: normalization

Kind help if anyone has detailed of what a amstrong database are and how are they useful any current important changes in this field or advice on where I may get info in which forum any link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a specific product called "Amstrong Database" but I have heard of [Armstrong's Axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong%27s_axioms) which are a set of axioms relating to the functional dependencies of relational databases. The axioms have been around a long time (mid 1970's).

There is an [IBM Research Paper](http://researcher.ibm.com/researcher/files/us-fagin/japan82.pdf) available.

I would think a Computer Science or Maths Department in your local University would be able to help.